# double lookup in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data around 25000 rows, for simplicity sake. i have 2 columns (submissionid, address,locationid), the table i want to compare it with has 4 columns(submissionid, address1,or address2,locationid). I want to retrieve the locationid from table 2 and put it in table 1. 
The address from the first table can either come from address1 column or address2 column. 
Most times, vlookup will solve the problem, however, some of the address are duplicates with different submissionid.

Ex: submissionid = 4, address = 25 main street, locationid = 7

submissionid=7, address = 25 main street, locationid= 8

Any way to solve this problem? I tried to use pivot table matrix, but my data set is too big!

Thanks

table 1

```
submissionid address            locationid
5            123 MainStreet     
4            123 MainStreet     
4            45 MLK BLVD        
6            11 Thames Rd       
7            4 RR
```

Table 2

```
submissionid address            locationid
4            123 MainStreet     7
5            123 MainStreet     10
4            45 MLK BLVD        4
6            11 Thames Rd       11
7            4 RR               10
```

As you can see, some of the submissionid takes more than 1 address, and the locationid can be nonexclusive. however, locationids are exclusive within its submissionid (ie, there can't be two of the same locationid for 1 submissionid)

Comment: It would help if you could provide a sample data set and what you expect. If you are looking to put the address in table1 from table2, I don't see why the duplicate is a problem as those duplicate are the same address. You would have the correct address in any case.

Comment: Sorry guys, i am not good with the format here. will try to edit.
but i am not trying to put address from table2 to 1. but rather, the locationid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to add a named array such as shown in D8:D13 in the image

[image: SO24189 example]

then:

```
=INDEX(locationid,MATCH(A2&"\"&B2,submissionid\address,0))
```

may suit (copied down), where the left-hand bordered area is also a named range.